# Render multiple data after patch request (React)

Tags: reactjs, patch

I am creating a small online shop where user selects items from page and check outs the cart. Everything to the very end works; the backend updates the stocks by subtracting their counter. The problem is that, when the user goes to the main page the last item in the cart is updated while the rest don't. Here is what my patch request looks like:

```
inventory.map(acc => {
            const subtractQuantity = acc.produce.quantity - acc.quantity
                fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/produce/${acc.produce_id}`, {
                    method: "PATCH",
                    headers: {"Content-Type" : "application/json"},
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        quantity: subtractQuantity,
                    })
                })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(res => handleUpdateProduce(res))
            })
}
```

Function (console log returns all items (as objects))

```
function handleUpdateProduce(food) {
    console.log(food)
    const updateProduce = produce.map(item => {
        if (item.id === food.id) {
            return food
        } else {
            return item
        }
    })
    setProduce(updateProduce)
}
```

How can I render an update of the counter from all items bought? Thanks for the help, I appreciate it!

Comment: why don't you use from redux or context?

Comment: Because im only allowed to use what i was caught in class.